# how to set the youtube-dl default download location to remote server?

Tags: youtube-dl

Is it possible to change the youtube-dl download location to another ftp server? If so, than how it can be done? I want to set the location of youtube-dl default download location to a remote ftp server.

Comment: Welcome please check this once, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

youtube-dl does not include an FTP upload functionality itself, but you can mount the FTP server to a local directory. That way, *every* application can use FTP, without any application-specific configuration necessary.

How to do that depends on your operating system. [Here are instructions for debian/Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/mount-remote-ftp-directory-host-locally-into-linux-filesystem), which should work on most Linux distributions as well, and [this question on our sister site serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/6079/64731) lists options on how to do it on Windows.

To make this the default behavior, create a [youtube-dl configuration file](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) (`~/.config/youtube-dl/config` on BSD/Linux/OSX, refer to [the link](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#configuration) for other locations) with the content:

```
-o '/my/ftp/mountpoint/some/subdirectory/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'
```

where `/my/ftp/mountpoint` is the mountpoint you chose for the remote server, and `some/subdirectory` is the path on that server. See the [youtube-dl documentation](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) for more information on output templates.